# Facebook RESTful API require_login() callback

Tags: api, facebook, authentication, callback, rest

I'm trying to authenticate a user through the RESTful API (not Connect) but I can't since the callback system does not work for me. I have a local app that creates the Facebook API object with my key and secret, then calls the Facebook API require_login() method; I am sent to Facebook login, I login, and then I am sent to `http://www.facebook.com/login.php?auth_token=<...>`, where there's another login with just a field for password (not username), I write it again, and after that I am redirected to normal Facebook home. What am I doing wrong? I have set the callback URL in the Facebook app proprieties. Does it have anything to do with the fact that it's localhost?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make the redirect in the end. It appears the "Canvas Callback URL" is what I needed to set, and not the Authentication one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you tell facebook to go to localhost, it has no way of knowing where to go. Is your app fbml or iframe? If iframe I'm guessing there's a remote chance that localhost would actually work since the frame loads and then your browser can find localhost. I'm not sure of that, I wouldn't bother trying. But if it's fbml, Facebook needs to be able to hit your server. Give it your external IP instead.